# Magento, i need define first product image as thumbnail

Tags: mysql, magento, e-commerce, thumbnails, product

I had imported my old oscommerce site with 15000 produts for magento!

But unfortably, the thumbnails are dont defined automatically

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdL0c.jpg

i can do maually, but 15000 produts is a larg number and i need sped a big amout of time for do it

if anywone can give-me a mysql command to set the first produts image as Base Image, Small Image and Thumbnail will be awesome

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try update them via api:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $images = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.list', $product['sku'])

    $imageFilename = $images[0]['file'];

    $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.update', array(
        $product['sku'],
        $imageFilename,
        array('types' => array('image', 'thumbnail')
    ));
}
```

Related documentation links:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_attribute_media

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product#catalog_product.list

Comment: it gives me this error -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/user/public_html/site.xxx/imagex.php on line 10

Comment: i had found this:

http://seanbreeden.com/post/18801892083/set-default-images-in-magento

now i have a doubt

what i put in this line: 

> AND ev.attribute_id IN (79,80,81);

Comment: You can find these ids in `eav_attribute` table: `SELECT  attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE entity_type_id = 4 AND attribute_code IN ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail')`

Comment: :( this mysql command doesnt work ... my temporary/tests website -> http://bit.ly/HaX5YY

Answer (score 0):

Im having a problem with this SQL code i got somewhere which is supposed to set your first image as image, small image and thumbnail:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
    AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
    AND ev.attribute_code IN ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail')
    AND mgv.position = 1;
```

Doesn't change any rows...

Also, my attribute_id's for image, small_image, thumbnail and media_gallery in Magento CE v1.6.2 are 106,109,493,703 using EMSupermarket template.

The following code also does nothing:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
    AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
    AND ev.attribute_id IN (106,109,493)
    AND mgv.position = 1;
```

Anyone how to do this correctly with my id's?

What happened with my oscommerce product import was that the imported product images only end up under the field name media_image, but not image, small_image or thumbnail so i want to copy the media_image values over to the other 3, any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I've notice it's the store_id in catalog_product_entity_varchar which seems to have the wrong store_id of "10" instead of "0".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found this page and ran that SQL command, and also did not get any results. But I modified it to work for me. Here is what I did.

First of all, I changed line 7 from:
    AND ev.attribute_code IN ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail')
to 
    AND ev.attribute_ID = '74'

the 74 is my unique attribute id for 'image'. You will have a different number here. You find it by looking it up in mySQL...
75  was for 'small_image' and 76 for 'thumbnail'.

So I ran this code 3 times, 1 for each of those attribute number. Each time I change line 7 ev.attribute_ID = '75' :

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
    AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
    AND ev.attribute_ID = '76'
    AND mgv.position = 1;
```