# how do I set small images to display (on front end) within magento 1.6+ as a bulk change?

Tags: image, magento

I've come across the following code that I thought may solve my issue however it's doesn't seem to do anything (query successful but applied to zero rows):

```sql
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
       catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
       catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET    ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND    mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND    ev.attribute_id IN (86,87,88)
AND    mgv.position = 1
```

for me these attribute_id's correspond to small image, thumbnail & media gallery from looking at eav_attribute table.

The images are displaying in the backend and the media gallery images can be seen on front end however small image & thumbnail do not display on the front end.

Looking at the catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table it only contains the media gallery attribute (88). Do I need to copy these, changing attribute to 86, to make it display on the front end? if so how do I go about this?

SQL is new for me, though I know how to copy and paste ;)

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat as you.
I did find this question and answer:
[Magento, i need define first product image as thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875026/magento-i-need-define-first-product-image-as-thumbnail/20587300)

But I also was looking for how to find the right values to set.

I believe if you run this code 3 times with each of the ev.attribute_id's that it should work.

```
    UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
    WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
    AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
    AND ev.attribute_ID = '76'
    AND mgv.position = 1;
```

Run that once for each of the attribute IDs (86, 87, 88).

I think that should work!