# Magento cant see products main image see place holder

Tags: php, mysql, magento, product

I upload lots of products into my shop, but I'm having some problems. I would like to know:

1. Is there any option to SPOT with MySQL query or PHP all products without main image that using the place place holders?
2. If I found the products and I know there is an image but not set to default can I set the the image with MySQL query?

This is not a hosting issue.

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875026/magento-i-need-define-first-product-image-as-thumbnail ... you may need to do some modification to the query

Comment: Is this work forlast version 1.7 ?

Comment: The first issue is to find the IMAGES that using PLACE HOLDERS or no image at all if it is the same

Answer (score 1):

Find all products that do not have an base image assigned...

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('image', 'no_selection')
;
```

With regards to your second point, assigning an image to a product, how you do this will depend on your own specific situation, but some sample code to get you started:

```
$fileSource = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/path/to/your/image.jpg';
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($fileSource, 'image', false);
```

To run the above code, you will have to [bootstrap Magento](http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/06/01/application-bootstrap-in-magento.html) first:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
if (! Mage::isInstalled()) {
    die('Magento is not installed.');
}
Mage::app('admin', 'store');
```

Comment: Hi i was looking for the SQL solution where do i RUN this code

Comment: I would probably advise against that, unless you have a good reason to.  You simply need to bootstrap Magento to run the code provided.  Please see updated answer